# Why is the following limit not 1?

Tags: limits, approximation, factorial

Consider $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)!}{(n!-n)!}\tag{1}$$

For large $n$, one can ignore $n$ wrt. $n!$ in the denominator. The limiting value should therefore approach $1$. However, as the plot shows, the limit blows up. Why is that?

[image: plot of the function whose limit is being taken]

Comment: Have you tried applying Stirling's formula?

Comment: It is false to say you can ignore $n$, it is inside the factorial.

Comment: You are expecting $f(f(n) - n)$ to asymptotically be near $f^2(n)$, which you can't take for granted.

Comment: Asymptotics need to be *way* finer when they're inside a factorial/gamma function. See for instance $(n+1)!/n!=n+1$.

Comment: The issue is $a_n \sim b_n$ does not imply $a_n! \sim b_n!$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio May you elaborate? How fine is *fine*? Say $f(n)$ is some continuous function in $n$. Let $g(f)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n+a)/f(n)$ for some finite $a$. When $f$ is a asymptotically a polynomial, the limit is a costant. As, this question shows, for factorials, the limit becomes $n^a$. Tomorrow, someone may come up with another function that would violate my intution even further. So my question is, exactly when can and can't we ignore $a$ wrt. $n$ in the argument?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $n\in\Bbb N$, then$$\frac{(n!)!}{(n!-n)!}=n!\times(n!-1)\times\cdots\times\bigl(n!-(n-1)\bigr)\geqslant n!,$$and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)!}{(n!-n)!}=\infty.$$You cannot simply ignore that second $n$ in the denominator since its presence makes the denominator *much* smaller than the numerator. And increasingly so as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the gamma function, taking logarithms and using carefully Stirling approximation
$$\log\left(\frac{(n!)!}{(n!-n)!}\right)\sim-n+\frac{n}{12 (T+1) (n-T-1)}+$$
$$\left(n-T-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (-n+T+1)+\left(T+\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \log (T+1)$$ where
$$T=\sqrt{2 \pi }\, e^{-n}\, n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$

A few values of the logarithms (which for sure confirm your observations and your plot)

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact value} & \Delta_n \\
 3 & 4.68466 & 4.78749 & 0.1028338 \\
 4 & 12.3601 & 12.4491 & 0.0889940 \\
 5 & 23.7684 & 23.8531 & 0.0846584 \\
 6 & 39.3711 & 39.4546 & 0.0835494 \\
 7 & 59.5886 & 59.6719 & 0.0833269 \\
 8 & 84.7528 & 84.8361 & 0.0832974 \\
 9 & 115.133 & 115.216 & 0.0833001 \\
 10 & 150.961 & 151.044 & 0.0833057 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Searching the $ISC$, it *seems* that the asymptotic error is close to
$$\Delta_\infty \sim 100\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\pi \, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}=0.0833058$$

Answer (score 3):

You have to work it out in each case.  $(n+\frac1n)^3-n^3$ grows but $(n+\frac1n)^2-n^2$ approaches a constant.

Let $g(n)=n!$ and $h(n)=\ln n!$.
Take the log of your ratio $f(n)$, and get $$h(g(n)) -h(g(n)-n)\\ \approx nh '(g(n))$$
Your 'minus n' term has to be so small it cancels the growth of $h'(g(n))$. Look up Stirling's formula, and work out how big $h'(g(n))$ is.